# Unittesting method which uses EF.Functions

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, .net-6.0

I have a method that should return all projects with a modified date older than 5 years.

```
var projekte = await this.db.Projects.Include(x => x.ProjectStatus)
            .Where(x =>
            x.ModifiedDate.HasValue 
            && EF.Functions.DateDiffYear(
                x.ModifiedDate.Value.AddYears(-5), 
                 this.dateTimeProvider.Today) >= 5)
            .ToListAsync(cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
```

and my unit test to cover this method:

```
[TestMethod]
    public async Task Handle_WhenCalled_ThenReturnProjekteWithGLKenntnisnameOlderThan5Years()
    {
        var today = new DateTime(2022, 8, 1);
        var projekt1 = new ProjektBuilder()
            .WithProjektId(new Guid("5a38062d-1992-4110-a49f-04cdf1eb21f0"))
            .WithModifiedDate(today.AddYears(-5))
            .Build();
        var projekt2 = new ProjektBuilder()
            .WithProjektId(new Guid("b5deaec7-17dd-4f2e-83fe-1badd7deeadb"))
            .WithModifiedDate(today.AddYears(-6))
            .Build();
        var projekt3 = new ProjektBuilder()
            .WithProjektId(new Guid("a7ca47ec-e5b0-4268-8df1-da562af1acd7"))
            .WithModifiedDate(today.AddYears(-5).AddDays(1))
            .Build();

        this.AddToInMemoryContext(new[] { projekt1, projekt2, projekt3 });
        this.dateTimeProviderFake.Setup(x => x.Today).Returns(today);

        var result = await this.testee.Handle(new GetProjekteToArchiveQuery(), CancellationToken.None);

        result.Should().BeEquivalentTo(new[] { projekt1, projekt2 });
    }
```

The InMemoryDb is setup like this:

```
protected void InitializeInMemoryContext()
{
        var randomAuditDatabaseName = $"{nameof(IAuditingContext)}_{Guid.NewGuid()}";
        var auditOptions = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<AuditDbContext>().UseInMemoryDatabase(randomAuditDatabaseName).Options;
        var auditContext = new AuditDbContext(auditOptions);

        var randomDatabaseName = $"{nameof(TContextInterface)}_{Guid.NewGuid()}";
        var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<TContext>().UseInMemoryDatabase(randomDatabaseName, b => b.EnableNullChecks(false)).EnableSensitiveDataLogging().Options;
       
        this.InMemoryContext = (TContext)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(TContext), options);
}

protected int AddToInMemoryContext<TEntity>(ICollection<TEntity> entities)
{
        foreach (var entity in entities)
        {
            this.InMemoryContext.Add(entity);
        }

        return this.InMemoryContext.SaveChangesAsync().Result;
}
```

When running the unit test I get the following error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: The 'DateDiffYear' method is not supported because the query has switched to client-evaluation. This usually happens when the arguments to the method cannot be translated to server. Rewrite the query to avoid client evaluation of arguments so that method can be translated to server.
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServerDbFunctionsExtensions.DateDiffYear(DbFunctions _, DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)

I guess it's because the DateDiffYear is specifically for the SQLServer but how can I unit test this method if this is the case?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

For this case, the best approach for really testing your code is to have a docker image with an SQL Server instance. The downside of this approach is that your unit tests would have a dependency, so in your CI/CD pipelines you will also need an SQL Server instance.

When you do not depend on any specific DB function, you can use `InMemory` or `SQLite` in memory, otherwise you need to test against the real technology. This is also the recommended approach by Microsoft:

- [Testing EF Core Applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/testing/)
- [Testing against your production database system](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/testing/testing-with-the-database)